# Selecting child elements subsequently in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to select the child elements subsequently.

Example:

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>23</li>
</ul>
```

There i want to select the child elements subsequently,

> 2 3  6 7 10 11 14 15 18 19 22 23

I am trying to select first even number and the next number then after 2 numbers again next even number and the next number. |

How can i do that in CSS?

Comment: Probably `li:nth-child()` is what you are looking for, reference here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class selector with [Functional notation(An+B)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Functional_notation).

```css
ul>li:nth-child(4n+2),/* where n would be 0,1,2.... so final value would be 2,6,10,... */
ul>li:nth-child(4n+3) {  /* here final value would be 3,7,11,... */
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great.. It worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You Can Solve The Problem by the css selector

```
ul li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: red;
}
ul li:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: red;
}
```